# Novel approaches to linear algebra and geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'll be studying Brannan's *Geometry* and Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* for one university course.

I would like to know if you can you suggest some books that offer a *unique* perspective on the material covered by such books and that can be therefore used as effective companions.

This unique perspective may include, for example, the emphasis of the geometric side of linear algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a different take on linear algebra, try [Practical Linear Algebra, A Geometry Toolbox](http://www.farinhansford.com/books/pla/) by Farin and Hansford.
[(reviews)](http://www.farinhansford.com/books/pla2/pla-reviews.html)

For geometry, try [Geometry: Euclid and Beyond](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-98650-0) by Hartshorne.
[(MAA review)](http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/geometry-euclid-and-beyond)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Can you tell me why exactly you recommend these books?

Comment: @Dal, I've added links to reviews.